# Fashion-MNIST using keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, mnist

Code:

```
import keras.datasets.fashion_mnist as fashion_mnist
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data() 
xtrain, xvalid, ytrain, yvalid = train_test_split(train_images, train_labels, test_size=0.33, shuffle= True)

xtrain = xtrain / 255.0
xvalid =  xvalid/255.0
ytrain = np_utils.to_categorical(ytrain )
yvalid = np_utils.to_categorical(yvalid)

history_dict = history.history
print(history_dict.keys())

history=model1.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=30, batch_size=64)

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

accuracy = history.history['binary_accuracy']
val_accuracy = history.history['val_accuracy']

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])  
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.show()
```

I get the following result,:
`KeyError: 'val_accuracy`' ,, I use `google.colab. dict_keys(['loss', 'accuracy'])`, only two variables are available. how to reach val_accuracy and val_loss?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To need to have `val_accuracy` and `val_loss`, you need to supply validation data to the `model.fit`. Try this:

```
history = model1.fit(train_images, train_labels, 
                  validation_data = (xvalid,yvalid), 
                  epochs=30, batch_size=64)
```

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. If it does please consider accepting/check-marking the answer.

Comment: how can I specify the number of epoches if I am increasing or decreasing  the number of batch size?

Comment: Glad it works. I don't get your question. You can just change epochs=30 to something else.

Comment: and is there any way to change the number of nodeds?

Comment: it has to be changed in something like `Dense()` or any other layers that you are using. You can the follow the article for more information: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-cnn-from-scratch-for-fashion-mnist-clothing-classification/